# Python3: Try block won't stop looping after recursive function call via caught exception

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, try-catch

I have a function that is a CLI menu for another program I'm working on. Each time the user enters input, the `input()` function is run within a `try` block.

If all try blocks succeed without catching any exceptions, there is no issue and the function behaves as expected; the function runs through, `return 1` is called and the function ends.

However, when an exception is raised, the user is notified why and then the current function is called recursively. When this occurs and then the user runs through the function, `return 1` is once again called, but this time the function immediately returns to the first try block in the function that had raised the exception previously.

The function in question:

```
def menu_userSetup():
    selection = 0; selected_key = 0

    if userSettings is None:
        userSettings = defaultSettings

    refresh_UI('\_ Test Setup _/', py3_version, bash_version, True)
    COLS = get_terminal_size().columns

    print('\n', 'Current Settings:'.center(COLS))

    z = 0
    for setting in userSettings:
        print('{}. {}: {}'.center(COLS - (COLS // 50)).format(z, setting, userSettings[setting]), end='\r')
        z += 1

    print('\n', 'Which setting would you like to set?'.center(COLS), end='')
    try: selection = int(input('{}'.format(' ' * (COLS // 2))))
    except KeyboardInterrupt: EXIT('Detected KeyboardInterrupt..')
    except:
        print('\n', 'Oops. That input is invalid!'.center(COLS))
        t.sleep(1.5)
        menu_userSetup()

    # the tuple function is used to return the key string according to its unordered index
    try: selected_key = tuple(userSettings.items())[selection][0]
    except KeyboardInterrupt: EXIT('Detected KeyboardInterrupt..')
    except:
        print('\n', 'That is not an available option!'.center(COLS))
        t.sleep(1.5)
        menu_userSetup()

    COLS = get_terminal_size().columns
    refresh_UI('\_ Test Setup _/', py3_version, bash_version, True)
    print('\n', 'Ok, {} selected!'.center(COLS - (COLS // 50)).format(selected_key))
    print('Type in your new setting:'.center(COLS))
    new_set = input('{}'.format(' ' * (COLS // 2)))

    if new_set.find('true') and new_set.find('t') != -1:
        new_set = True
    elif new_set.find('false') and new_set.find('f') != -1:
        new_set = False

    if new_set is not None or '':
        userSettings[selected_key] = new_set
        print('\n', '{} has been set to {}!'.center(COLS - (COLS // 50)).format(selected_key, new_set))
        t.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print('\n', 'Oops. That input is invalid!'.center(COLS))
        t.sleep(1.5)
        menu_userSetup()

    refresh_UI('\_ Test Setup _/', py3_version, bash_version, True)
    COLS = get_terminal_size().columns

    print('\n', 'Current Settings:'.center(COLS))

    z = 0
    for setting in userSettings:
        print('{}. {}: {}'.center(COLS - (COLS // 50)).format(z, setting, userSettings[setting]), end='\r')
        z += 1

    r = input("Press enter to return to the main menu or 'r' to make another change!\n")
    if r == 'r':
        menu_userSetup()

    print('returning...'); t.sleep(2)
    return 1
```

Is it perhaps simply not possible to recursively call a function from an `except` block?
If it's not, how can I achieve the same effect of catching errors leading to a recursive function call?

Note: This solution does *not* need to be compatible with python 2.x, but any extra info as a bonus is welcome nonetheless!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

The issue seems to be that when `return` is called from within the function (that has been called from within the exception block), it returns back to the last line of the exception ***where the function was last called from.***

It does not return to the location where the function was first called from initially.

I tried just adding `return 1` after the recursive call of the function within the except blocks, and that worked!

```
try: selection = int(input('{}'.format(' ' * (COLS // 2))))
except KeyboardInterrupt: EXIT('Detected KeyboardInterrupt..')
except:
    print('\n', 'Oops. That input is invalid!'.center(COLS))
    t.sleep(1.5)
    menu_userSetup(); return 1
```